# Eclipse IFileEditorInput on a temporary file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

The Eclipse ClassFileEditor requires either an [`IClassFileEditorInput`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ui/blob/master/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/javaeditor/IClassFileEditorInput.java) or an [`IFileEditorInput`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.ide/extensions/org/eclipse/ui/IFileEditorInput.java), it does not accept a normal [`IStorageEditorInput`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.ide/extensions/org/eclipse/ui/IStorageEditorInput.java).

The problem is that I have binary data as `InputStream` objects. I'd like to open an editor and this works great with `IStorageEditorInput` except for class files.

I am looking for a way to turn the stream in a temporary file and then create an `IFileEditorInput` on it. However, I cannot find any way how to create a temporary file as an `IFile` object, needed for an `IFileEditorInput`. Somehow an `IFile` is required to be in the Eclipse workspace.

Comment: IFile resources are always in the workspace (although that might just be a link to data held elsewhere). I don't see any way to create an automatically deleted temporary IFile.